# ibm_boto3 connection refused error

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, object-storage, data-science-experience

ibm_boto3 list_objects working in the IBM Data Platform Jupyter Notebook however,

ibm_boto3 list_objects not working in the local terminal.

## example code

```
client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket)
```

I was able to print out the client object using print(client)

But when I try the `list_objects` then `ConnectionRefusedError(61, 'Connection refused'))` happened.

[ibm_botocore connection refused screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8n3bk.png)

The reason for trying the ibm_boto3 in my local since I want to upload the folder from my local to the IBM Data Platform project. My local folder contains a lot of files so I want to use the ibm_boto3 sdk from my local terminal to upload easily.

I created the folder in the IBM Data Platform project using the jupyter notebook ipynb file but also when I tested the put_object in my local terminal it was not working which was the same situation for list_objects.

How can I run the list_objects in my local terminal?

I am using `Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda 4.3.0 (x86_64)`

Much appreciated,

Answer (score 1):

Insert to Code from Notebook generates credential which is only specific to the project that you created on DSX , so it limits you to only the bucket created for your project and denies access to any other bucket. Also i think* it make sure those credentials can only be used in Notebook on DSX.

So what you need to do is 
Go under Apps and Services under settings in DSX

https://dataplatform.ibm.com/settings/services?context=analytics
and click manage in IBM Cloud for your Cloud Object Storage service.

[image]

or

Go to Bluemix.net(IBM Cloud)
https://console.bluemix.net/services/ 
and locate your COS service and then open it

Then Click New Credenitals and Select "Manager" as Role, Name it anything you like.

[image]

Click Add.

Now from your python client on local machine.
As describe in this
https://github.com/IBM/ibm-cos-sdk-python
Instead of resource , we will create client.
Replace, API-KEY , RESOURCE_INSTANCE_ID  with values from your newly generated credentials.(Click View Credenitals)
Also replace bucket-name with your desired bucket-name.

Make sure to install
 `pip install ibm-cos-sdk`

```
from botocore.client import Config
import ibm_boto3
api_key = 'API_KEY'
service_instance_id = 'RESOURCE_INSTANCE_ID'
auth_endpoint = 'https://iam.bluemix.net/oidc/token'
service_endpoint = 'https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net'
cos_client = ibm_boto3.client('s3',
                      ibm_api_key_id=api_key,
                      ibm_service_instance_id=service_instance_id,
                      ibm_auth_endpoint=auth_endpoint,
                      config=Config(signature_version='oauth'),
                      endpoint_url=service_endpoint)
cos_client.list_buckets()
cos_client.list_objects(Bucket="bucketname")
```

Thanks,
Charles.

Comment: Hi I tried the api_key(apikey) in my Manager Role and the service_instance_id(iam_serviceid_crn) like "iam-ServiceId-<credential for service instance id>" and I follow your example auth_endpoint and the service_endpoint but it was showing "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied" but it is the right bucket listed in the bucket overview. Much appreciated!!

Comment: Wow! Thanks!! I reuse the Editor's apikey and the service instance id then I change the service_endpoint from private to the public as you suggested in your example code. It was working to print out the list_objects!! I want to vote your answer but due to my low reputation it was not possible. But really really thank you!! X100 :)